# How does dot operator relate to Namespaces?

Tags: python

As i was going through python basics and introduction one thing that really confuses me is namespaces. I cant seem to understand how they work.

For instance in Cs50 course they brush over the concept but i wanted to get clearer understanding of it if possible because it seems very important to grasp. For example this code:

```
import cs50

x = get_int("x: ")
y = get_int("y: ")
print(x + y)
```

Causes this error:

python calculator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/workspaces/20377622/calculator.py", line 3, in 
x = get_int("x: ")
NameError: name 'get_int' is not defined

What is wonder is why when cs50.get_int() is written instead interpreter doesn't throw an error? Is it because cs50 library is seen as its own namespace structure and . goes into that structure to get_int location? What does . operator do exactly here in terms of namespaces  ?

Comment: There are no "namespaces" in Python, so the premise of the question is not clear to me. You get the error because `get_int` is really not defined. Did you mean to use `cs50 .get_int`?

Comment: using get_int() means it is a function that should be declared and defined within your python file (if it isn't a built-in one)..using smth like cs50.get_int() means you're accessing this function through the library called cs50

Comment: You are importing all the structure inside cs50, but you have to specify when using something from it (cs50.get_int()). If you don't, when running the code the interpreter will look for get_int only inside the main file you are running. This avoid the interpreter to load unnecessary data to the context.
If you want to import only this function from cs50 (or all others inside cs50) and bring them to the same context of the file you are working at runtime, you can make ```from cs50 import get_int``` or ```from cs50 import *```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html might be a good read.

Answer (score 0):

You `import cs50`, so you have a name "cs50", you can use

```
cs50.get_int()
```

but namespaces has no name `get_int`.

You can use `from cs50 import get_int` to import name "get_int"

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, let's talk about modules.

In Python, "module" is used to refer to two things. First, a piece of code, usually a .py file. Second, the object that is created for the namespace of that code when it is run.

When you do `import foo`, a couple of things happen.

1. Python checks if `foo` has already been imported. If so, it skips to the last step.
2. Python looks up where it can find `foo`, for example if there is a `foo.py` in the right place.
3. Python creates a fresh namespace object and stores a reference to it in `sys.modules['foo']`
4. Python runs the code that it found, using that namespace object as its "global" namespace.
5. Python goes back to the importing module, and adds a global variable `foo` in the namespace of importing module that points to `sys.modules['foo']`.

You can then access any global variable `bar` that was created in the foo.py module by using `foo.bar`.

You could also use `from cs50 import get_int` which works like this:

```
import cs50
get_int = cs50.get_int
```

... except that the name `cs50` is not assigned to.

---

If you're asking why it works that way: this way different modules can define the same name for classes, functions or constants, and they won't conflict with each other.

Now, if you know you're only using `get_int` from `cs50`, and you don't have any other `get_int` either in your main module or that you imported, the from ... import syntax is very useful to not have to write `cs50.get_int` every time you want to use it.